Android: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in proguard after updaing gradle plugin to 8.7
I have a problem. After our project was upgraded to the new version of gradle (8.7). I'm getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in minifyDebugWithR8 gradle task. There is no information where exactly it happens. Any ideas other than replacing all collections with thread-safe version?
I have tried to isolate the code that is causing the problem. But it is somehow random. I cannot find any connection. When I think I have found the place, I have tried to comment it out (compilation works), then I write new, normal code and the problem happens again.
`* Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':my_app:minifyDebugWithR8'.         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)         at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)         at
....
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47) Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete         at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.5.10.java:0)         at com.android.tools.r8.T.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:5)         at com.android.tools.r8.internal.so.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:82)         at com.android.tools.r8.internal.so.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:32)         at com.android.tools.r8.internal.so.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:31)         at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:79)         at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:3)         at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:332)         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:782)         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable.execute(R8Task.kt:856)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)         at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)         at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:174)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)         at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:133)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)         ... 2 more Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException         at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.M.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:748)         at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.M.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:2135)         at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.M.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:1593)         at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:1471)         at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:233)         at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:1)         at com.android.tools.r8.internal.so.a(R8_8.5.10_22aedce5751c5724ec7f9ababa2e0e8592ff733648b0ef6249782cbca92180e8:28)         ... 34 more`

I have the same issue ... I've reported it but google didn't answer working fine with 8.4.2

Try downgrade the Android Gradle Plugin from 8.5.0 to 8.4.1

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
